# How to combine multiple article into single volume with auto generated table of content

Tags: table-of-contents, article

How do I combine multiple articles into a single volume with auto generated table of content. Is it possible?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).  Please, add a MWE to show us your problem and what you already have tried out.

Comment: I have prepared multiple articles with cej.cls but I have no idea to combine that.

Comment: PLEASE: add an example with at least one minimal article and your attempt, to combine several of those articles in one document.

Comment: Have a look into `combine` package, for example

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - Please post an answer that elaborates on your suggestion to use the `combine` package.

Comment: @Mico: Done so....

Comment: Some organizations with this requirement use an external custom script to compile the pdf files output by (La)TeX into the final volume, applying final page numbers directly to the pdf pages.

Comment: If  the combine class is no longer usable as the answers suggest, can we archive all the questions using the combine class and remove them from the internet? I wasted two days trying to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** As noted [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/591145) the combine class is no longer usable with current versions of LaTeX. Please disregard this answer...

---

Here is a MWE using the [`combine`](https://ctan.org/pkg/combine) class, as suggested in the comments.

### `main.tex`

```
\documentclass{combine}
\usepackage{combinet}
\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \begin{papers}
    \import{a1}
  \end{papers}
\end{document}
```

### `a1.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\author{Author}
\title{Title}
\begin{document}
  \maketitle
\end{document}
```

### Result

[image: result]

---

The `combine` class allows `import`ing complete LaTeX documents, essentially ignoring the `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` commands, with options for handling sub-document packages, etc. The `combinet` package works with the `combine` class to add imported document titles and authors to the main TOC when they are imported.

---

Having used this combination to create a complete journal volume from multiple articles, I can tell you there are many challenges to this task. For example, the `authblk` package will not behave as expected, and likewise for `biblatex`. However, similar problems emerge if you are going to try to roll your own title-blocks, etc.

Comment: This answer is way too minimal to be useful.

Comment: The combine class is no longer usable, please see edit above.

Answer (score 0):

create a single .tex file named as your wish (ie., book.tex, master.tex)

then include all your article in that same file like below, and dont forget to delete \documentclass{cej}, \begin{document}, and \end{document} in each and every article.

```
\documentclass{cej}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\include{article1} %% include your multiple article
\include{article2} %% 
\include{article3} %% 
....
....
\include{articleN} %% 
\end{document}
```

Comment: These suggestions fail to address important issues, such as what to do with the title- and date-related information that must have been associated with the original stand-alone LaTeX documents.