# "Extra \endgroup" error when using the combine document class

Tags: pdftex, combine

It gives just such an error, Google has not found an answer. Help me please.

The program code itself

```
\documentclass[11pt]{combine}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{misccorr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\title{Лабораторная работа №1}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{combine} 
\maketitle 
\tableofcontents 
\clearpage
\begin{papers} 
\coltoctitle{HelloWorld} 
\label{HelloWorld}
\import{HelloWorld} 
\coltoctitle{KursTitle}
\label{KursTitle}
\import{KursTitle}
\coltoctitle{kurs}


\end{papers} 
\end{document}
```

and errors

```
> ! Extra \endgroup. \document ->\endgroup 
>                       \let \mainjobname \jobname \def \c@lmainauxfile {\jobn... l.10 \begin{document}
>                       ?
```

Comment: the combine class can't be used with a current latex. It is not compatible.

Comment: How can you solve this problem?

Comment: use something else, e.g. look at the subfiles package.

Answer (score 4):

Not really an answer, but...

I (the original developer) have been aware of this for some time and contacted maintainer about this in November 2020. I further contacted the maintainer last month with a solution. I have not (yet) had any response from the maintainer.

My suggested solution was, in the class code, to comment out the initial `\endgroup` in the `\c@ladocument` macro.

Comment: I don't quite understand what can be done here. What would the program be executed. Tell me and if possible write a line of code that can be replaced.
I tried replacing \ documentclass [11pt] {combine} with \ documentclass [11pt] {article} and it didn't work.

Comment: @user238890 My suggestion was that the code in `combine.cls` needed changing. If you did not understand that then don't change the code. In any case don't change the code. The `article` and `combine` classes do very different things.

Comment: @Peter Wilson: I tried your fix, but unfortunately, I got a lot of "undefined control sequence" errors.

Comment: Apologies, I can't try and help any more. It is up to the maintainer of the class. Please contact him.

Answer (score 1):

See [Simon Dispa's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/655986/255699) based on [Peter Wilson's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/591171/255699) answer.

It simply adds the following before `\begin{document}`

```
\makeatletter
\let\document\c@ladocument\begingroup%
\makeatother
```